# python replace value in json file

Tags: python, json

I have a json file named test.json and I need a python function for substitute some specific values in the same file.
The json file is:

```
[
  {
    "ParameterKey" : "HOME",
    "ParameterValue" : "/home"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey" : "Shell",
    "ParameterValue" : "/bin/sh"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "EnvHost",
    "ParameterValue": "localhost"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "EnvUser",
    "ParameterValue": "stall"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "Type",
    "ParameterValue": "super"
  }
]
```

I need to replace only "Shell" and "Type" to other values but I'm struggling to do so.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code and explain what you are struggling at.

Comment: what are you trying to do? do you want the result to be a python object or another json file?

Comment: seems case of overzealous closing this is a perfectly good question, maybe it could use a little tweaking but I've seen way worse with hundreds of upvotes

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
import json 
with open('/path/to/josn_file.json', 'r') as file:
     json_data = json.load(file)
     for item in json_data:
           if item['ParameterKey'] in ["Shell","Type"]:
              item['ParameterKey'] = "new value"
with open('/path/to/josn_file.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(json_data, file, indent=2)
```

Comment: It works! I have added 'sort_keys=True' to json.dump because the result was inverted, and added 'open' after 'with'.

Comment: What if you don't necessarily know the format of the JSON but you know there are placeholder values that you want to overwrite? For example, say that throughout your JSON you have "__REPLACE__" and you want to replace that with a given string no matter where it's located. How can that be done?

Comment: See my answer for s.g. question